# Find and replace a specific number with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string

```
string absoluteUri = "http://localhost/asdf1234?$asdf=1234&$skip=1234&skip=4321&$orderby=asdf"
```

In this string I would like to replace '$skip=1234' with '$skip=1244'

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(absoluteUri, @"$skip=\d+", "$skip=1244");
```

Unfortunately this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

The output should be:

```
"http://localhost/asdf1234?$asdf=1234&$skip=1244&skip=4321&$orderby=asdf"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is a special character in regular expressions (it's an anchor).  You need to escape it in both the expression and in the replacement string, but they are escaped differently.

In the regular expression, you escape it with a `\` but in the substitution you escape it by adding another `$`:

```
Regex.Replace(absoluteUri, @"\$skip=\d+", "$$skip=1244");
```

Comment: Great, thank you! The escaping with \ did the trick. I'm not sure why but it works with and without escaping the replacement string.

Comment: Probably because `$s` is not a valid replacement string and it ignores it.  I'd recommend using `$$` in the replacement even if it is not strictly necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment.
Just little fix. Need to do:

```
absoluteUri = Regex.Replace(absoluteUri, @"\$skip=\d+", "$skip=1244");
```